# How to make a check for compliance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I get an error `Cannot read property 'general' of undefined` when I enter in the search is not existing data in the array. What I need to make a condition to track the error?

When I try to set a condition, I fail

```
{
   (selectUser.general === !undefined) ?

    <Grid >
       <Grid.Column mobile={16} tablet={6} computer={5}>
          <Image src={selectUser.general.avatar} />
       </Grid.Column>
    <Grid.Column mobile={16} tablet={10} computer={11}>
      <h1>{`${selectUser.general.firstName} ${selectUser.general.lastName}`}</h1>
      <h3>Position: {selectUser.job.title}</h3>
      <h3>Company: {selectUser.job.company}</h3>

      <h4>
         Contact:
         <p><Icon name='mail' size='small' /> <a href="mailto:Gerry_Hackett77@gmail.com">{selectUser.contact.email}</a></p>
         <p><Icon name='phone'  size='small' /> <a href="tel:8959840132">{selectUser.contact.phone}</a></p>
      </h4>
      <p><strong>Address:</strong> {`${selectUser.address.street}, ${selectUser.address.city}, ${selectUser.address.country}`}</p>
     </Grid.Column>
   </Grid>

   :

   <h2>Error</h2>

 }
```

Full code example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7oxkkpqoj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error suggests that selectUser is undefined and hence you need to check for its existence before using it like

```
{
   (selectUser && selectUser.general) ?

    <Grid >
       <Grid.Column mobile={16} tablet={6} computer={5}>
          <Image src={selectUser.general.avatar} />
       </Grid.Column>
    <Grid.Column mobile={16} tablet={10} computer={11}>
      <h1>{`${selectUser.general.firstName} ${selectUser.general.lastName}`}</h1>
      <h3>Position: {selectUser.job.title}</h3>
      <h3>Company: {selectUser.job.company}</h3>

      <h4>
         Contact:
         <p><Icon name='mail' size='small' /> <a href="mailto:Gerry_Hackett77@gmail.com">{selectUser.contact.email}</a></p>
         <p><Icon name='phone'  size='small' /> <a href="tel:8959840132">{selectUser.contact.phone}</a></p>
      </h4>
      <p><strong>Address:</strong> {`${selectUser.address.street}, ${selectUser.address.city}, ${selectUser.address.country}`}</p>
     </Grid.Column>
   </Grid>

   :

   <h2>Error</h2>

 }
```